# passing a variable to a method with a system.object parameter in c#

Tags: c#

My application is simple. I use a timer that executes a method every 15 seconds.

I have my application currently set to have a call back timer open a method that creates a string, then calls my logic method.

What I want to do is create my string in the timer method, then pass the string directly to my logic method. Is it possible to pass a variable to a method with a system.object parameter inside of it?

```
//This is the piece of code in my timer method (methodA) which calls methodB

ThisTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(methodB));

        private void methodB(object sender)
        {
        string theString= "MyString";
        methodC(theString);
        }

 private void methodC(string theString)
        {
        }
```

What I want to do is

```
//This code jumps directly from methodA to methodC
string theString= "MyString";
ThisTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(methodC(system.object,theString)));

     private void methodC(object sender, string theString)
            {
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lambda to close over the variable(s) you want to use when providing the callback for the timer:

```
string theString= "MyString";
ThisTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(sender => methodC(theString));
```

---

```
private void methodC(string theString)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass the object needed by the TimerCallback in the Timer constructor like this

```
string str = "something";
Timer t = Timer(methodC, str, 0, 1000);
```

The str object will be passed into the timercallback method.